# HttpContext.User.Identity?.Name is Null after migration from .net framework v4.6.2 to .net core 6 with NTLM authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core, .net-framework-version

I'm migrating an application from .net framework v4.6.2 to .net core 6 but I'm having an error when trying to access the user's name attribute, it's coming null.

In the .net framework the name was being accessed like this:
`HttpContext.Current.User.Identity?.Name`

Now in .NET core I'm trying to access it this way, since the 'Current' attribute has been removed:
`HttpContext.User.Identity?.Name`

In my startup I added this code:

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddNegotiate();

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
```

And in my launchsettings i've added this:

```
 "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:65198",
      "sslPort": 44557
    }
  }
```

Comment: should be able to use User.Identity.Name.  It'll include the domain, so split on "/"  HTTPContext is already a part of AspNetCore..

Answer (score 0):

If by chance you're using YARP for a strangler fig-type implementation pattern, it would seem this is not supported

https://microsoft.github.io/reverse-proxy/articles/authn-authz.html

> Windows, Negotiate, NTLM, Kerbereos
>
> These authentication types are often bound to a specific connection. They are
> not supported as means of authenticating a user in a destination server behind
> the YARP proxy (see #166. They can be used to authenticate an incoming request
> to the proxy, but that identity information will have to be communicated to
> the destination server in another form. They can also be used to authenticate
> the proxy to the destination servers, but only as the proxy's own user,
> impersonating the client is not supported.

https://github.com/microsoft/reverse-proxy/issues/166

(from Tratcher's comment)

> YARP will not support forwarding NTLM auth requests through the proxy because
> it does not support the connection level affinity required for NTLM. Note
> there's not a check in place to prevent this, it will just fail most of the
> time.
>
> You can authenticate from the client to YARP or from YARP to the destination
> (or both), just not end-to-end through the proxy.

I discovered this when doing some research on ways to migrate a WebForms app to something more modern. If it doesn't apply to your situation, I hope it helps someone down the road.